How to make Visual Studio launch a powershell/bat script when starting asp.net webform app without debugging?
The example in MS docs shows how to do it with console app and makefile.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customize-build-and-debug-tasks-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#define-tasks-with-tasksvsjson
My project is a asp.net webforms application and I would like to be able to manipulate the behavior of the browser via batch or ps script. I do not want to get a makefile involved because I am not trying to configure a custom build. I do not want the task to run before or after a build. I want it to run when the application starts which I don't think is quite the same as a post-build task. Any suggestions on how I should go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Why not just run/launch the applcation, and then run your scripting objects against the running instance of the browser? it not all that clear why Visual Stuido matters at all here? If you using some kind of browser, automation, then simply create the instance of the browser, and point it to local host on your dev box - that should work just fine, should it not?

Visual Studio is the IDE I'm using. I thought I made that clear.

Sure, but what browser automation tool you looking to use here? (Selenium for example?). So, you can hit f5 in VS to spool up the application and the browser launches. At that point, you can launch additional copies of a browser pointed to that same URL (localhost). So, this comes down to what browser automation tool you are looking to use here. Some "wishy washy" statement about using js will not cut it here. If you looking to automate the browser for testing, then you need some system to "host" that copy of the browser - not really sure how to do this any other way....

I'm not using any browser automation tool, beyond vs. I'm not really looking for anything too fancy here. I just want a script that can be launched that will close old tabs/windows in the browser every time an instance of the  asp.net application is launched. Also, I'm not looking for the script to be launched before or after a build. There's a lot of docs on this but that's not what I think I need.

If you hit f5 from vs to launch the application, then without question that browser instance is attached to the vs session. You close the browser, OR if you hit the stop button in vs, then the browser that is open will and should shut down (along with any tabs opened). However, any instance of the browser opened outside of that f5 + launching of the browser of course is not attached to the vs session started from hitting f5, and of course will not close automatic for you.  But, any tabs having been opened in that new copy of the browser that was launched should shut down.

Having stated above, I fully admit I not helping you much here.....

VS doesn't have such time that suit your requirement:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2022
Please consider Albert's solution.
